# Get last occurrence of item in array of arrays (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following array:

```
[[ "7", "4" ], [ "7", "43" ], [ "7", "4" ], [ "7", "" ], [ "6", "2" ], [ "7", "8" ] ]
```

How can I get the last occurrence of each distinct first element.

I would need the above array to be converted into:

```
[ [ "6", "2" ], [ "7", "8" ] ]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Making it valid JavaScript would make it so much easier for people to help you.

Comment: I tried iterating over the arrays and adding the last element found of each key into a new array. But it seems messy and slow.

Comment: sorry about that. It's the logger output and I though the Array word made it clearer. Editing it now.

Comment: *" I thought the Array word made it clearer"* . No. Makes the data useless to run code against. The square braces are extremely clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Map and use the first element as a key:

```js
const data = [[ "7", "4" ], [ "7", "43" ], [ "7", "4" ], [ "7", "" ], [ "6", "2" ], [ "7", "8" ] ];
 
const result = Array.from(data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.set(item[0], item)
  return acc;
}, new Map()).values());

console.log(result);
```